# Unity Models Import Without Color

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to import a model into Unity, the colors aren't imported with the model. I've attached pictures to show what is happening.[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqGZr.png) [Model When Imported In Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F7PY.png)

I tried using different modeling programs and I expected the model to import with the correct colors but everything in the model was only one color.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a model, you get a folder called "Material". In that folder you should find the material your model is using. That folder however is empty cause the texture is not in your project.
Try import your model texture and once its imported apply that texture to the model.